# Laravel carbon retrieve record even when it shouldn't

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am searching by start and end date or with a weekday, which kind of works fine however if weekday is equal to 'WE' and today's  weekday is equal to 'WE' it still brings back results even when $today date is < than endate.

```
public function show($id)
{   
    $weekMap = [
        0 => 'SU',
        1 => 'MO',
        2 => 'TU',
        3 => 'WE',
        4 => 'TH',
        5 => 'FR',
        6 => 'SA',
    ];
    $todayWeek = Carbon::now()->dayOfWeek;
    $today= Carbon::now();
    $weekday = $weekMap[$todayWeek];
    $event = Event::with('businesses')
       ->where('startdate', '<', $today->format('Y-m-d'))
       ->where('endate', '>', $today->format('Y-m-d'))
       ->orWhere('weekday', '=', $weekday)
       ->get();
    dd($event);
    return view('events.showEvent', compact('event'));
}
```

If I change orWhere to where, results are all good, however user not always enters a weekday so it can be empty. I want it to work like this:

output everything where startdate < today and where endate > today and if weekday is not empty, output everything where startdate < today, endate > today and weekday = $weekday. I hope that makes sense.

//edit

sample data:

[data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYYjh.jpg)

So what I want is really search by frequency so it would look like this:

if frequency = daily
compare start and end with today's date.
if frequency = weekly
compare start and end with today's date and weekday.

bring back all results for frequency = daily+weekly

Answer (score 0):

you can use if condition in query like this:

```
$query = Event::with('businesses')
   ->where('startdate', '<', $today->format('Y-m-d'))
   ->where('endate', '>', $today->format('Y-m-d'));

   if ($weekday != '') {
       $query->where('weekday', $weekday);
   }

   $event = $query->get();
```

also

condition `if ($weekday != '')` check `$weekday` isset or not you can use

`if ( ! is_null($weekday ))` instead

Comment: the problem with that is this code is bringing back only 1 result where weekday = 'WE' that part is correct however it doesn't bring back results that match start and end date but don't contain $weekday

Comment: $weekday always has a value because it' set as carbon, what it has to match against is where('weekday') so match against 'weekday' in database and if it's not empty run that where statement

Comment: so it has to match something like if  (!empty($event->weekday) but it keeps giving me an error that collection is empty

Comment: could you edit your question and put sample table data and show me what you want to get?